# Solving system of ODE´s

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the system

$$ \ddot{x} + \frac{k}{2m}x = g  $$
$$ \ddot{\theta} + \frac{3g}{2l} \theta = 0 $$

where k, g and l are constants. My textbook (in mechanics) proposes that $ x = Re(A_1 e^{i\omega t}) = C_1 \cos{(\omega t + \alpha)} $ and $ \theta = C_2 \cos{(\omega t + \alpha)}$. I want to solve for the angular frequency, $ \omega$.

If I plug that in it yields

$$ -\omega^2x + \frac{k}{2m}x = g $$
$$ -\omega^2 \theta + \frac{3g}{2l} \theta = 0$$

or

$$\begin{bmatrix} -\omega^2 + \frac{k}{2m} & 0 \\ 0 & -\omega^2 + \frac{3g}{2l} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ \theta \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} g \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

**Q:**
The book then draws the conclusion that the determinant of the matrix must be zero. Why is that?

If it would be on the form $Ax = 0$, then A can't be invertible for x to be non-trivial. But what about $Ax = b$? Why do we want A to be non-invertible?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the matrix solutions. The form of the DE enforces what $\omega$ must be:
$$\omega=\sqrt{\frac{k}{2m}}=\sqrt{\frac{3g}{2l}}.$$
It should be noted as well that your proposed $x$ is only the solution to the homogeneous equation. The general solution is
\begin{align*}
x(t)&=C_1\cos\!\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{2m}}\,t+\alpha\right)+\frac{2mg}{k}\\
\theta(t)&=C_2\cos\!\left(\sqrt{\frac{3g}{2l}}\,t+\alpha\right).
\end{align*}
If your $x$ doesn't have the constant term, it cannot satisfy the full DE.

However, what's puzzling me mightily about this solution are the following questions, which you need to answer:

1. Why should the $\omega$ for the $x$ solution equal the $\omega$ for the $\theta$ solution?
2. Why should the phase angle $\alpha$ for the $x$ solution equal the phase angle for the $\theta$ solution?
3. Do you have any initial or boundary conditions that $x$ and $\theta$ have to satisfy? If so, that would enable you to solve for $C_1, C_2,$ and possibly $\alpha.$

Comment: Thank you, I got it. You could also make the first ODE homogenious by the substitution$ x = \frac{2m}{k} g $. The questions origin is describing this https://imgur.com/a/WFTIz9Y config. The ODE's are from linearized oscillation close to equilibrium. I do not know why the angular momentum $\omega $ is the same for $ x $ and $ \theta$. $x, \theta $ are generalized coordinates by the way.